# Why is my search query returning undefined, while my page populates with the term's results? Using business catalyst

Tags: javascript, html, search, business-catalyst

I'm trying to get the search term to appear in the URL. What am I doing wrong?

```
<form name="catsearchform74255" method="post" onsubmit="processSearch(this)" action="/Default.aspx?SiteSearchID=2248&ID=/search-results&amp;keywords=">
        <div class="input-field search-box">
            <input id="CAT_Search" type="search" name="CAT_Search" placeholder="What are you looking for?" class="white" required="true">
            <label class="label-icon" for="CAT_Search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
            <i class="material-icons">close</i>
        </div>
         <script type="text/javascript">
        function processSearch(form) {
            form.action = form.action + CAT_Search.value;
        }  
    </script>
    </form>
```

Comment: have you tried just changing `method="post"` to `method="get"` and removing the `submit` handler? `method="get"` will append all of the variables from the form as query strings in the URL

Comment: Why doesn't the server script just get this from the POST parameter instead of the URL?

Comment: @MichaelCoker , I tried that. It fixes the url, but my search results are no longer posted on the page.

Comment: Can you please provide a link as well. There might be something else interfering. I had 2 search boxes on the same page, and I forgot they had the same *id* attribute and that created a problem for me.

Comment: @DautMolahasanov , you can find the link here: http://okunstage.businesscatalyst.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `method="post"` to `method="get"`.
2. Update any server-side code referencing post variables to reference get variables. For example, in PHP code, change `$_POST["CAT_Search"]` to `$_GET["CAT_Search"]`.

Also, the correct format for the `required` HTML attribute is either `required=""` or `required="required`.

Comment: This is a hosted Saas system, you can't edit server side code

Answer (score 0):

#### Code

This can be done with JS, you can't edit the method as Business Catalyst expects a post for this form.

If you change the form to the following:

```
<form name="catsearchform74255" id="searchForm" method="post" action="/Default.aspx?SiteSearchID=2248&ID=/search-results&amp;keywords=">
    <div class="search-box">
        <input class="cat_textbox_small" type="text" name="CAT_Search" id="CAT_Search">
        <input id="submitForm" onclick="submitFormScript()" type="button" class="cat_button" value="Search">
    </div>
</form>
```

and then add the following jQuery:

```
function submitFormScript() {
    var searchAction = $("#searchForm").attr("action");
    searchAction = searchAction + $("#CAT_Search").val();
    $("#searchForm").attr("action", searchAction);
    $("#searchForm").submit();
}
```

#### Explanation

By adding the ID's to the fields on the form and then taking `type="submit"` off the input button we can edit the form action before we submit the form.

In the JS we are getting the form action, adding on the value of the search box (users input) and then setting that back to the form `action` attribute.  After that we have the URL that we want to send to the next page so we can then submit the form.